# ZF2 annotationbuilder manytoone -> show select

Tags: zend-framework, annotations, zend-framework2

I have 2 Entities (Text and TextCategory) with a manytoone relation. Now, I create forms for each entity with the annotationbuilder and in the text form I want to show a select to choose a textcategory. I tried

```
  /**
   * @var \Backend\Text\TextCategory
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="categoryId")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Backend\Text\TextCategory", fetch="EAGER")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
   * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")
   * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Kategorie:", "target_class":"Backend\Entity\TextCategory"})

   */
  private $categoryId;
```

but this only shows me a text field. What am I doing wrong, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aaand once again I found out what the problem was (without really knowing why). Turns out I have to leave out the @ORM\Column ... line:

```
  /**
   * @var string $categoryId
   * 
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Backend\Entity\TextCategory", fetch="EAGER")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
   * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")
   * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
   * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
   * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Class:",  "property":"name", "target_class" : "Backend\Entity\TextCategory"})
   * @Annotation\Attributes({"value":"0"}) 
   * 
   */
  private $categoryId;
```

aaaand suddenly it works!